# Errors in Play Mode test setting Animator parameters

Tags: unity, c#, unit-testing

I've just started adding tests to my game project in Unity. I know the difference between EditMode and PlayMode tests. I've written a PlayMode test that triggers a change to the Animator internally, but this fails as the parameter in the Animator doesn't seem to be changing. I also get the warning `Animator is not playing an AnimatorController` everytime I call `GetFloat` or `SetFloat`, which I suspect is an indicator of my issue.

**Script under test**

```
public class ChangeDirection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    public void SetDirection(Direction direction)
    {
        var directionVector = new Vector2(0f, 0f);

        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Up:
                directionVector = Vector2.up;
                break;

            case Direction.Down:
                directionVector = Vector2.down;
                break;

            case Direction.Left:
                directionVector = Vector2.left;
                break;

            case Direction.Right:
                directionVector = Vector2.right;
                break;
        }

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", directionVector.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", directionVector.y);
    }
}
```

**PlayMode test**

```
public class ChangeDirectionTests
{
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator SetDirection_DirectionUp_VerticalChanged()
    {
        var gameObject = new GameObject();
        var animator = gameObject.AddComponent<Animator>();

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", 0f);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", 0f);

        var changeDirection = new ChangeDirection();
        changeDirection.animator = animator;
        changeDirection.SetDirection(Direction.Up);

        Assert.AreEqual(0f, animator.GetFloat("Horizontal"));
        Assert.AreEqual(1f, animator.GetFloat("Vertical"));
    }
}
```

**Test output**

```
SetDirection_DirectionUp_VerticalChanged (0.017s)
---
Expected: 1.0f
  But was:  0.0f
---
at ChangeDirectionTests.SetDirection_DirectionUp_VerticalChanged () [0x00063] in /home/samuelslade/source/games/pokemon-world/Assets/Tests/EditMode/ChangeDirectionTests.cs:22
---
Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
```

The warning around using the `new` keyword to create a `MonoBehaviour` has this further detail:

```
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor ()
ChangeDirection:.ctor ()
ChangeDirectionTests/<SetDirection_DirectionUp_VerticalChanged>d__0:MoveNext () (at Assets/Tests/PlayMode/ChangeDirectionTests.cs:17)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding how this works, so any direction to help me understand how best to approach writing tests in Unity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes here:

1. `AddComponent<T>()` adds a new component in its *default* state. That means the `Animator` you create this way has its `runtimeAnimatorController` property in the default state of `null` - you didn't tell it *which* Animator Controller Graph it should be using. Not every such graph has parameters named "Horizontal" and "Vertical", so before you try to write or read such parameters, you need to provide a graph that has them.
2. As your error message tells you, it is not valid to create a free-floating `MonoBehaviour` in user code via `new`. Scripts deriving from `Component` must be attached to a `GameObject`. It looks like what you meant to write was something more like...

   ```cs
   var changeDirection = gameObject.AddComponent<ChangeDirection>();
   changeDirection.animator = animator;
   changeDirection.SetDirection(Direction.Up);
   ```

   This creates the new `MonoBehaviour` instance and attaches it to the parent `GameObject` in one operation, letting the engine wire up everything needed behind the scenes to make the component work.

I think both of these issues would be easier to solve if you made a prefab object that has the animator and control script you want to test already set up (with the appropriate animator controller assigned and the `ChangeDirection` script attached). Then your test script can load that asset and instantiate a copy of it to test.

Comment: Thanks for your response - it makes a lot of sense! I didn't realise that about the default state when using `AddComponent`. Also, using `new` on the `ChangeDirection` class was a clear oversight! I'll give the prefab approach a go.

Comment: Switching to using the prefab and not calling `new` on my script fixed the tests - thanks!